# Why does precision increase with decimal points?

Tags: measurements, error-analysis

Precision is how close repeated measurements are to one another. So why does the precision increase with more decimal points? How are these two things related?

Answer (score 1):

The number of decimal points do not change this they are rather an effect of limited precision.  A measurement always should come with an uncertainty e.g. due to statistical processes of the measurement apparatus. E.g. for measuring length with a standard ruler the unit of the smallest mark might be a good uncertainty. For anything below that you would need a more precise ruler.

So e.g. (assuming that the smallest marks are mm) one might give a measurement as $15 \pm 1$ mm where the $\pm 1 $ is the uncertainty. Now why not give more decimal points? Because it does not make sense! If we know that the measurement was (simplifying how uncertainties work) between $14$ mm and $16$ mm giving the measurement as $15.256 \pm 1 $ mm still tells us exactly the same information. We can only ever trust our measurement to the digit where our uncertainty is. So if a value is given with more decimal points basically tells you that the uncertainty was calculated (at least it should have been) to be at most a correction at the same power as the last digit given.
E.g. if someone gives a length measurement as $15.1234$ mm you can assume that the error is at most of the order $10^{-4} $mm.

Note that this discussion assumes that repeated measurements are correct i.e. that the mean value around which the measurements fluctuate is stable.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a measuring instrument with accuracy that's known to be $\pm\Delta{x}$ and you perform $n$ measurements of the same physical quantity, the value measured at the $i$'th measurement is $m + \delta{x}_i$, where $\delta{x}_i$ is the error in this $i$'th measurement, and:

$$-\Delta{x} \leq \delta{x}_i \leq \Delta{x}\tag{1}$$

And we find that after $n$ measurements, the measured quantity $\hat{m}$ can be expressed as the average over all measurements:

$$ \hat{m} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(m+\delta{x}_i) = m + \underbrace{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta{x}_i}_{\Delta{m}}\tag{2}$$

Where I have indicated the overall error $\Delta{m}$ as the term we would like to analyze. Note that the maximal measurement error occurs when *every* $\delta{x}_i$ is equal to either $\Delta{x}$ or $-\Delta{x}$, so we have:

$$\text{max}(\left|\Delta{m}\right|) = \Delta{x}\tag{3}$$

But even more importantly, in general we can see that:

$$ \left|\Delta{m}\right| \leq \Delta{x} \tag{4}$$

So note that while $n$ increases, $\delta{x}_i$ will in general, be randomly scattered in the interval $[-\Delta{x},\Delta{x}]$ and as a result, we intuitively see that the more we average over errors $\delta{x}_i$ within said interval the more the overall error tends to zero. This actually can be rigorously formulated via [The law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), but I hope that I managed to give a feel for why at least intuitively, performing repeated measurements under said conditions increases the precision of the obtained result.

With regards to decimal figures: the impact would be to have more [*significant* decimal digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) that we can account for in our result, due to $(4)$, which I have shown, and also due to the proposition that $\left|\Delta{m}\right|$ decreases as $n$ increases, which I have only intuitively shown.